# Error writing a file - it gets doubled

Tags: java, file

Sorry for how unclear the title may sound, I just don't know how to explain it.

So, I'm trying to read some lines frome a File, modify them and then add them to another file.

This is the original file:

```
line number one
line number two
line number three
```

And so on...

But when it comes to print it into another file, I get this:

```
line number one
line number one line number one
line number one line number one line number two
line number one line number one line number two line number two
```

This is my code

This is the part that reads the original file

```
try {
   File f = new File(path);
   try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(f); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {

   while ((aux=br.readLine())!=null) {

       //easyDecryp is the method that modifies the line.
       //there's nothing wrong with it.

       output += easyDecryp(aux)+"\n";
       aux="";
   }
   br.close();
   fr.close();
}       

} catch(IOException e) {
System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

And HERE I write into the new one

```
try {
   File f = new File(path);
   try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f); PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw)) {
       pw.println(output);
   } 
} catch(IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Output is the variable that holds the lines. All of them.
It should read line by line and then be written into the new file, like this:

```
output = line1
//New line added
output = line1 \n line2

//Note the new line tag between every line
```

Comment: the code you have doesn't show where you write the file.  What is the "output" variable?

Comment: Post the code how you write the content into another file. Are you using **output** variable, which is append line content. **output += easyDecryp(aux)+"\n";**

Comment: You don't need explicit `Closeable.close()` at the end of try-with-resources, BTW.

Comment: easyDecryp(aux) inserts the duplicate lines. Please verify it in  debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `easyDecryp(aux)` is returning the line, and then you are doing `+=` on top of that. This is why your line is getting duplicated.